# Is it ok to use the anaconda distribution for web development?

Tags: python, django, web, anaconda

I started learning Python working on projects involving data and following tutorials advising to install the anaconda bundle, to take advantage of the other libraries coming with it.

So did I and I got confortable with it, I liked the way it manages environments.

During the last months, I have been teaching myself web development with `django`, `flask`, continuing to use the anaconda python. But most of the time I install the dependencies I need with `pip install` though (inside the conda environment).

I've never seen any tutorials or podcasts mentioning the conda environment as an option for developing web apps so I start to get worried. Is it for a good reason?

Everywhere its the combination of `pip` and `virtualenv` that prevail. And `virtualenv` isn't compatible with anaconda that has its own `env` management system.

My newbie question is: Will I run into problems later (dependencies management in production or deployment maybe?) using the anaconda distribution to develop my web apps?

Comment: In my last company we were forced to use Windows as an OS. Since most of my work required numpy et al. I didn't have much choice but to use Anaconda and then Spyder as an IDE. I built a full app in Django that I then ported over to one of our AWS instances to actually host it. I can't say it was a full-blown web development project because it was a tool to be used internally, but certainly it was possible to build on a different OS, and handling dependencies on the Linux system was trivial compared to actually building the thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Albeit, with a few caveats. First, I don't recommend using the big Anaconda distribution. I recommend installing Miniconda(3) ([link](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html#regular-installation)).

To set up the second caveat, it's important to figure out what part of `Conda` you are talking about using. Conda is two things, that is, it is has both the functionality of `virtualenv` ([an environment manager](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)) and `pip` ([a package manager](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html)).

So you certainly can use `Conda` in place of virtualenv (an environment manager) and still use pip within that `Conda` environment as your *package manager*. Actually this is my preference. Jake VanderPlas had a good comparison of [virtualenv vs Conda as an environment manager](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/#Myth-#5:-conda-doesn't-work-with-virtualenv,-so-it's-useless-for-my-workflow). Conda has a more limited offering of packages thus I try to keep everything as one package manager (`pip`) within that environment. One problem I've found with `virtualenv` is you can't choose any particular flavor of Python, e.g. 2.7, 3.3, 3.6, etc like you can seemlessly install that version of Python within your environment with `Conda`.

Here's a [list of command comparisons](https://conda.io/docs/commands.html#conda-vs-pip-vs-virtualenv-commands) of `Conda`, `virtualenv`, and `pip` if that helps clear things up a bit on how you can utilize `Conda` and/or `virtualenv` and/or `pip`.

Comment: the link for "list of command comparisons" is now a 404. Looks like Conda moved the documentation. 

the archived page for that can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20181204182007/https://conda.io/docs/commands.html

Comment: Using `virtualenv` you can just do `virtualenv --python=python3.7` if you want to use that interpreter. Note that it has to be installed on your host system first.